# Agregar data a un Chartjs

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, chart.js

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web en Angular con un grafico de barras (Chartjs), consumiendo los datos de una API externa. Hasta ahora todo esta perfecto, la api me devuelve los datos en consola perfectamente. Pero ni bien levanto ng serve, me aparece el grafico vacío y no hay ningun error en consola.
Este es mi **grafico.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { CovidService } from '../../services/covid.service';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grafico',
  templateUrl: './grafico.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grafico.component.css']
})
export class GraficoComponent {
  chart = [];

  constructor( private covid: CovidService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.covid.covidApi().subscribe(res => {
      /*const result = res.location.timelines;
      const {deaths, confirmed, recovered} = result;*/
      const muertes = res.location.timelines.deaths.timeline;
      console.log(muertes);

      this.chart = new Chart ('canvas', {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          datasets : {
            labels: Object.keys(muertes),
            data: muertes,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            fill: false
          },
        },
        options:{
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes:[{
              display: true
            }],
            yAxes:[{
              display: true
            }]
          }
        }
      })
      });

  }
}
```

Este es mi **grafico.component.html**

```
<h4>Grafico</h4>
<br>
<div>
    <canvas id= "canvas">{{chart}}</canvas>
</div>
```

No se donde está mal. Esto es lo que me devuelve en consola, nada más.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo poco que veo, tu información solo contiene 0, o existe algún valor con mayor a 0?

Comment: También, viendo la documentación tengo entendido que el objeto debe tener coordenadas x/y, es decir algo como lo siguiente `data: [{x:'2016-12-25', y:0}] `

Comment: Hola @OscarLudick sisi existe un valor mayor a cero al aumentar las fechas

Comment: Te referis a la propiedad data dentro de datasets??

Comment: Asi es, la propiedad data debe ir como un array de  objetos [{x, y}]

Comment: Sigue sin aparecer nada

Comment: Ok puedes intentar especificar un alto y un ancho a tu canvas `<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>`

Comment: Y una duda, por que estas usando datasets? Esto es para que manejes múltiples conjuntos de datos es decir tu objeto de datasets debe estar en un arreglo: `datasets: [{labels: Object.keys(muertes),...}]`

Comment: Puedes revisar la estructura de un dataset : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/data-structures/#parsing. Creo que lo que tu estas buscando es lo que te comente, un data, sin el datasets, `data: [{x:'2016-12-25', y:20}, {x:'2016-12-26', y:10}]`